# Returning an array without a Leak!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, nsarray, memory-leaks

[sender LoadDataComplete:arrDetailData];
I am returning this array like this from an objective C class in my my class which inherits ViewController...if I write [arrDetailData release] below this...i get crash...
Please advise on it...how to get this array without a leak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you autorelease it ?

Comment: Quoted from apple doc: "An autorelease pool is an instance of NSAutoreleasePool that “contains” other objects that have received an autorelease message; when the autorelease pool is deallocated it sends a release message to each of those objects. An object can be put into an autorelease pool several times, and receives a release message for each time it was put into the pool. Thus, sending autorelease instead of release to an object extends the lifetime of that object at least until the pool itself is released (the object may survive longer if it is retained in the interim)."

Comment: Link - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 2):

@devaditya you should use autorelease instead of release

```
[arrDetailData autorelease];
```

you can write this statement before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using [array relese] it will release the object very soon it may crash your app..so use autorelese..If you mean you want to remove the objects from array  use [array RemoveAllobjects].. [Refer  about memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)