# How to fix this potential memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I am new to objective c and I don't understand how there is a memory leak here:

```
MessageCustomCell *cell = [[MessageCustomCell alloc] initAutoreleaseWithLine:currentLine AndId:message.UID];
[[cell dateTime] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:message.Date]];
[[cell from] setText:message.From];
[[cell play] setTitle:@">" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[formatter release];   
return cell;
```

On the return cell; line the analyzer says that there is a "potential leak of an object allocated on line 207 and stored into cell." This is the line where cell is allocated but I'm returning cell so how is this a leak? 
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How does `initAutoreleaseWithLine:` method look?

Comment: How about using autorelease ? Check my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930182/returning-an-array-without-a-leak/4930204#4930204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, based on the name, is you are trying to return an auto released object in an init function. The static analyzer makes assumptions that instance methods beginning with `init` return ownership to the caller (increased retain count) even if you call it `initAutorelease`. The same goes for methods that begin with `new`. You will continue to get analyzer warnings until you change the name but what you are trying to do needs to be a convenience method of the class.

```
//Signature
+(id)cellWithLine:(int)line andId:(NSString*)mid;

//Sample Call
[MessageCustomCell cellWithLine:currentLine andId:message.UID];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in a static method I can't use currentLine and message.UID to set some instance variables I need later on. While I'd prefer to set the autorelease on init, its more important that I set the instance variables.

Comment: @Alex Inside the static method you create an instance, and if your instance variables are not publicly exposed you can access them with `->`

Comment: Unless I'm missunderstanding you, for this to be successful I'd need to change the relationship of MessageCustomeCell from being a UITableViewCell (interface MessageCustomCell: UITableViewCell) to having a UITableViewCell instance variable. The current structure of my project would not make this practical.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me, what you are wanting to create is a convenience constructor. The MessageCustomCell will have a static method that allocates, and initializes an instance of itself and return an autoreleased value. This way static analyzer is happy and you get your desired results. Here is a quick example http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1084240

Answer (score 0):

```
return [cell autorelease];
```

Also, you are releasing formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Before Fixing potential leaks we need to know what is retain and release. Retain is allocating memory, Release is deallocating memory.

NSstring *str = [[NSstring alloc] init];
Here we are allocating memory to 'str' variable. In the same .m file we need release the memory for the variable after completing the functionality of it.
Simple write in the code [str release];
It won't cause any memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

Unless your method name begins with "new" (as in newMessageCell), "alloc" or contains "copy", the returned object is expected to be an autoreleased object. Your code returns the object with a reference count of 1 and a well-behaved caller will not decrement it beyond that. If the caller wishes to retain the cell to take ownership of it, it will do so.

To fix this leak, simply autorelease the cell.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.  However, in the MessageCustomCell initialization I call [self autorelease]. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: "Unless your method name begins with "new" (as in newMessageCell), the returned object is expected to be an autoreleased object." -- Wow, REALLY not. `-alloc...` and `-copy...` all return non-autoreleased objects too. The solution to this problem (autoreleasing the cell object) is correct, but the first sentence of your answer is going to spawn a thousand memory leaks.

Comment: @Dan Good catch. I wrote the answer in haste and omitted those two. My bad. I've edited the answer.